PHP: Processing POST multidimensional arrays with ambiguous depth
I created a form builder and processing class that I use within my own framework, but ran into an issue I wasn't accounting for, POST arrays.
Essentially, the class takes the name of the POST variable and uses it internally, only interacting with the POST variable once when cleansing/validating the form submission. I had an issue and tracked it to a dimensional POST variable and then decided it would be prudent to update the class so that it can process multidimensional arrays.
Well, the issue is that I can't seem to figure out a good way to convert a string representation of the query variable such as $name = 'product[1]'; to $value = $_POST['product'][1];. It's fine if I only worry about one level, but I wanted a more robust solution that could potentially support any depth.
While it's arguably not the best idea to have a form with a multidimensional array that goes 5 levels down, I realized making a function do this was a puzzle. Imagine the following all being supported by the same function:
function foo($name) {
 $bits = explode('[',$name);
 foreach ($bits as $id => $v) $bits[$id] = rtrim($v,']');
 // magic happens below
 return $_POST[$bits[0]][$bits[1]]...[$bits[x]];
}

This would result in being able to handle any depth:
// $_POST['product'][22] = 'armchair';
$name = 'product[22]';
$value = foo($name);
echo $value
// armchair

// Absurd example
// $_POST['product'][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8] = 'extreme';
$name = 'product[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]';
$value = foo($name);
echo $value;
// extreme

The ugly solution which does not handle an ambiguous depth:
function bar($name) {
 $bits = explode('[',$name);
 foreach ($bits as $id => $b) $bits[$id] = rtrim($b,']');
 switch (count($bits)) {
  case 2:
   return $_POST[$bits[0]][$bits[1]];
  case 3:
   return $_POST[$bits[0]][$bits[1]][$bits[2]];
  case 4:
   return $_POST[$bits[0]][$bits[1]][$bits[2]][$bits[3]];
  case 5:
   return $_POST[$bits[0]][$bits[1]][$bits[2]][$bits[3]][$bits[4]];
  case 6:
   return $_POST[$bits[0]][$bits[1]][$bits[2]][$bits[3]][$bits[4]][$bits[5]];
  default:
   return $_POST[$name];
 }
}

I feel there must be a way to go from a string representing a multidimensional array to accessing the value specified from that array.

Generally if you have a structure of indeterminate depth the solution is going to involve recursion.

@Sammitch you mean a loop.

@YourCommonSense I mean what I said. In a narrow case like this where you're traversing a set path you can also use a loop, but recursion would work just as well.

How to access and manipulate multi-dimensional array by key names / path?
